# WPF XAML Rotate 90° in UWP margin issue

Tags: windows-10-universal, rotatetransform

Hi I'm struggling with rotation in XAML. I found a solution that LayoutTransform should solve this issue, but on Windows Universal Plattform this option isn't available!

This is my Code:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="long long long long long long long long text"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="90"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" />
    </StackPanel>
```

But as you can see there are an huge margin between the colored boxes and the textblock as you can see here:

[image: margin]

So my first guess was to add an `Width="30"` property to the textblock, but this isn't working as you can see here (not only the offset is the problem, but the cropping is the problem):

[image: width]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the LayoutTransform control of the WinRTXamlToolkit. Following links should help.

[Github Source](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) link and [Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS6a9dVunq4&feature=youtu.be&t=3m16s) link